# Matching an item number to the appropriate abbreviated item number in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of abbreviated item numbers with corresponding commission rate data. When I download sales data it contains complete item numbers. I want to match the complete item number to the correct abbreviation (another tab in the workbook). The correct abbreviation matches the beginning of the corresponding item number- the abbreviations vary in length between 3 and 5 characters.

How can I retrieve the appropriate abbreviation given the complete item number?

Comment: I m assuming that  the shorter abbreviated item numbers can have characters in common with longer abbreviated item numbers. That is, you can have abbreviated numbers such as "12" and "123" and "1234". Correct?

Comment: Richard, would you mind providing several examples of abbreviations and the corresponding item numbers?

Comment: So we have 057GK which is the abbreviation for part numbers 057GK12, 057GK20 and 057GK31... I want to write a formula which finds 057GK given any of the part numbers above

Comment: Are there always just 2 characters after the part number (as your example)? Or could there be 057GK5 and 057GK124?

Comment: Is there any rule which indicates when the abbreviation is 3, 4 or 5 characters long?

Comment: In your question, you mention that the abbreviations are 3-5 characters in length. Would it ever be the case that a shorter abbreviation could the the first characters in a longer abbreviation. That is, using your example, could there be a code 057G?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that addresses the varying lengths of the item numbers and abbreviated codes as well as the possibility that abbreviated codes of different lengths share some initial numbers or letters.

It uses three helper columns that do exact match `VLOOKUPs` on the abbreviated code of the first 3, 4, and 5 characters, respectively, of each item. A match may be found on any, all, or (in the case of bad data) none of these lookups for an abbreviated code.

The fourth calculation column contains the formulas that select among the results of the three `VLOOKUPs`.

The selection rules are simple. If a single match is found in the list of abbreviated codes, the matched code is returned. If two or three matches are found, the match with the greatest number of characters is returned. If no matches are found for an item, the formulas return the error value #N/A.

The selection expressions in the fourth column of the calculations are array formulas and must be entered with the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination (i.e., the formula in the first row must be so entered and then can be copied down to the bottom of the item number list).

For the example formulas below, a list of full item numbers is in cells `A2:A10` of Sheet 1. A list of abbreviated codes is in cells `A2:A10` of Sheet 2. The helper formulas are in columns `B-D` of Sheet1 and the selection array formulas are in column `E` of that sheet. (The example array formula should be fully visible by moving the scroll bar to the right.)

**The Formulas**

```
Cell B2:   =VLOOKUP(LEFT($A2,3),Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10,1,0)
Cell C2:   =VLOOKUP(LEFT($A2,4),Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10,1,0)
Cell D2:   =VLOOKUP(LEFT($A2,5),Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10,1,0)

Cell E2:   =IFERROR(INDEX($B2:$D2,1,MAX(NOT(ISERROR($B2:$D2))*TRANSPOSE(ROW($1:$3)))),#N/A)
```

I'll briefly explain how the fourth formula works.

- `NOT(ISERROR($B2:$D2))` returns a three-element array of TRUE/FALSE values, with TRUE for the helper columns (in a particular row) that have a match and FALSE otherwise. For example, {TRUE, TRUE, FALSE}.
- `TRANSPOSE(ROW($1:$3))` simply provides the array {1, 2, 3}, each number denoting one of the helper columns.
- Their product - `NOT(ISERROR($B2:$D2))*TRANSPOSE(ROW($1:$3)))` - produces an array with the values 1, 2, or 3 for the columns with a match, and zero otherwise, as in {1, 2, 0}.
- The `MAX` function returns the largest number in that array, which corresponds to the helper column that returned the match with the greatest number of characters. In the {1, 2, 0} array, `MAX` returns 2, for a match in column C, the 2nd of the helper columns.
- `INDEX` then selects the abbreviated code in column C.
- Finally, the `IFERROR` function returns #N/A if no matching abbreviated code was found.

**Sheet1**

[image: Sheet1e]

**Sheet2**

[image: Sheet2]

Comment: This is rather cool and more flexible than my existing approach. I'm going to implement this today. Thank you bro!

Comment: Richard, if this resolved your problem, it would be great if you could accept the answer (the check mark). I'll get credit for a useful response and others will be able to easily tell that the answer worked for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the item number is always followed by two digits/characters, as in the example data (057GK12, 057GK20 and 057GK31), then the following will give you the item number:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)
```

If you're trying to find the cell that has the abbreviation in it, you'd do something like this:

```
=MATCH(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),Sheet2!B:B,0)
```

If you're trying to find the full value from the abbreviation, you'd do something like this:

```
=MATCH(B1&"??",Sheet1!A:A,0)
```

These only give the first result in the column. This also assumes the item numbers and abbreviations are formatted as text and not values.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the item numbers are of varying lengths so there isn't a set format. I think I'll update the table to include each item number so that I can use a vlookup.